# iOS Multiple Scrolling Sections - Right way

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout

i have question regarding one screen which i should implement in app, as iOS giving us various possibilities i don't know which one is the best practice for this current task.

[image]

Sections as visible on the screen should scroll and while we select one of them, should show unique data.

**Scrolling Data Is Static.**

> My ideas:

```
1) Create multiple tableView's to support scrolling and get button actions.
2) Using the scrollView - programmatically add buttons on scrollview with multiple IBActions.
3) Modify UIPickerController to support such template.
```

As i mention there are lot of options and maybe i have missed more, but question is: In which way you would finish this tasks and how do you think is right way to handle such a design because on iPhone 5s we know that this `UIView` will be resized and will be smaller so `UIView` should be inserted in `ScrollView` itself.

Comment: I'll suggest 1) Create multiple tableView's to support scrolling and get button actions.

Comment: Multiple UITableView is a quick way to do it. Since you custome it, you can use the same cells, UI for both. Multiple ScrollView can be used to, but maybe more work, or it's new way UIStackView. But I'd still recommand UITableView. It's quite easier to read after a month if you need to debug or add entries.